# Loading data into root route of ember router when it's created outside of application.create()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When you want to use classes you created in `Em.Application.create()` in your router you need to specify the router outside of the application.create. But because the application is automatically initialized the router doesn't route to the `/` route.

You used to be able to defer the initialization by adding `autoinit: false` to the application.create. Now you are supposed to use `App.deferReadiness()` and `App.advanceReadiness()`. However this doesn't appear to work.

And I can't seem to escape the feeling that you are "supposed" to do it differently.

I added the minimal code to show the problem below. There is also a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NXA2S/6/)

**EDIT:**

Apparently there is a new router in ember I kinda sorta overlooked that. I've changed the code to the new router, but guess what it still doesn't work :P

```
window.App = App = Em.Application.create({
    ApplicationController: Em.Controller.extend({}),

    ApplicationView: Em.View.extend({
        template: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet}}'),
    }),

    ExtendedPatientController: Em.ObjectController.extend({}),

    ExtendedPatientView: Em.View.extend({
        classNames: ['patient-view', 'extended'],
        template: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{name}}')
    }),

    Patient: Em.Object.extend({
        name: undefined,
    }),
});

App.Router.map(function (match) {
  match('/').to('application', function (match) {
    match('/').to('extendedPatient');
  })
});

App.deferReadiness();

App.ExtendedPatientRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller) {
    controller.set('', App.Patient.create({
      name: "Bert"
    }));
  },
  renderTemplates: function () {
    this.render('extendedPatient', {
      into: 'application'
    });
  }
});

App.advanceReadiness();
```

Comment: I would say you don't have usually to call defer/advanceReadiness at all. Could you try to define your views and controller outside of the Application.create()? Something like App.ExtendedPatientController = Ember.ObjectController.extend() ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually doing a **lot** more work than you need to here.

Here's all the code that you need to make your example work.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="patient-view extended">
    <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

App:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();

App.Patient = Em.Object.extend({
  name: null
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Patient.create({
      name: "Bert"
    });
  }
});
```

The working fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/NXA2S/23/

Let me explain it a bit:

- When you go to `/`, you are entering the automatic `index` route. All you need to do to show something on the screen for that route is to implement an `index` template. The easiest way to do that when you're getting up and running is to put your template in your `index.html`. Later, you will probably want to use build tools (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271651/define-application-template-in-ember-view-in-the-most-recent-ember-js-build/14273004#14273004) for more information).
- You can control what model is displayed in a route's template by overriding the `model` hook in its route handler. In the case of `index`, the route handler is `App.IndexRoute`. In this case, the model is a brand new `App.Patient`.

You will probably want to implement controllers and events. You can learn more about the router on [the Ember.js website](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/)

Comment: Awesome thanks! When do you override the `model` and when do you override `setupController`? Doing the extra work was a bit on purpose though. I developed a ember app somewhere last year. And I wanted to get to grips with the latest version.

Comment: You override `model` to specify which model your route represents (it becomes the `model` property of your controller). You override `setupController` to set up other properties on your controller that you want your template to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

So the new router does solve this problem and does feel a bit shinier.

I finaly found out how to do this basic example this is what happens in the router:

```
App.Router.map(function (match) {
  match('/').to('extendedPatient');
});
```

This what needs to happen in the views:

```
ExtendedPatientView: Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['patient-view', 'extended'],
    //You need to specify the defaultTemplate because you extend the view class
    //instead on initializing it.
    defaultTemplate: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{name}}')
}),
```

You do not have to defer the readiness in the app the new router fixes that.

And in the route you do not need to specify the `renderTemplates` so the router now looks like:

```
App.ExtendedPatientRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller) {
    controller.set('content', App.Patient.create({
      name: "Bert"
    }));
  },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXA2S/28/