# Define application template in Ember.View in the most recent Ember.js Build

Tags: ember.js

I recently upgraded to the most recent Ember.js build (built from the GitHub page.)

When using the new router, does this no longer work?

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Hello")
});
```

I much prefer to define my templates in my js file rather than index.html. I believe it is much cleaner. However, the above does not render!

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Ember 1.0, templates should be defined in `index.html` or in separate files that are provided to your application via a build tool.

Some examples:

- [For Grunt](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates)
- [For Brunch](https://npmjs.org/package/ember-precompiler-brunch)
- [For the Rails Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails)
- [For Iridium](https://github.com/radiumsoftware/iridium-ember)
- [A Standalone Precompiler](https://github.com/tchak/barber/blob/master/README.md)

If you really, really want to put your template in JavaScript, you can put this in your application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.MyView}}
</script>
```

And then define your view:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Whatever you want here")
});
```

That said, the happy path in Ember is to use external templates for each of your routes, either in your HTML when you're getting started, or using a build step so you can keep them out of your index.html.

Comment: I had a feeling that this would be the answer. I used to think of my templates as "belonging to" my views, but it seems that Ember is moving in the direction where the templates are used to build your UI and views are only needed to respond to user events (sometimes.)

I'm sure this is the best way to do things, but I'll have to start thinking a little differently!

Comment: that was a key moment for me too. views are optional components of templates which is a weird thought.

Comment: Is there any way to connect an {{outlet}} to an application template rendered using a custom view?  Using {{outlet}} doesn't seem to connect properly.