# What a better way to handle templates in Ember.js, that isn't putting them in <script> tags?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So I'm building an Ember.js application. I've got more than two routers now, so it's becoming a lot harder to justify putting all these templates in `index.html` as `<script>` handlebars.

I can't seem to figure out how to have handlebar templates outside of the html! The other thing is that I'd like to avoid more dependencies if possible. So no pipeline, grunt libraries, or similar.

So to clarify:

- I already stuff templates in `index.html` via `<script>` tags, I don't like it.
- I don't want to jump back 20 years and put HTML in strings inside my javascript.
- AJAXing static views seems ridiculous.

Comment: 20 years ago javascript wasn't invented yet. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without adding anything to the stack I don't see how you could do it other then putting them in `index.html` or in code one way or the other.

With adding stuff to your stack you should probably read this: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271651/define-application-template-in-ember-view-in-the-most-recent-ember-js-build/14273004#14273004) by Yehuda Katz himself.

You could compile your templates in code like so:

```
App.View = Em.View.create({
  template: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet}}');
});
```

or if you are extending the view:

```
App.View = Em.View.extend({
  defaultTemplate: Em.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet}}');
});
```

or you could register them like so

```
App.register('template', 'ViewName', Ember.Handlebars.compile(template));
```

Comment: ...HTML as strings? Sorry, I don't think that's better than all in `index.html` as `<script>` bodies.

Comment: It's might not be but you didn't ask for a better solution. You didn't want build tools and you didn't want them in your index.html. This does exactly that.

Comment: You might be able to pre-compile them using node and then `deferReadiness` until they're loaded into Ember.TEMPLATES. But that would probably mean adding something to the stack. with something like: https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile (requires node)

Comment: The title clearly states "the best way" and the body of my comment denotes me wanting something better than `index.html` `<script>` tags.

Comment: Marked as an answer. Looks like I'm adding to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found so far is to use a command line tool like Grunt. You set the paths where your templates are (so you can organize your handlebars files nicely), and grunt will automatically compile all the views into a single, minified JS file that you can include, whenever you create or modify a template.

Because your templates are already compiled you can ship your application with a much smaller version of handlebars.

You can see an example of a configured Grunt file for that here : https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

Comment: Sure. But grunt 0.4 is really not hard to install. iirc just add --devel or somehting like that when you download grunt.

Comment: I'd rather not have to install edge software just to get my released software to work.